# How to use node modules outside of webpack encore files?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, node-modules, webpack-encore

I have started using webpack encore in my Symfony 5 web app and still haven't figured it all out.
I'd like to use node modules outside of webpack encore files but I can't find a way of doing this.

For example I have installed Datatables and I'd like to use it in a JavaScript file inside the *public/assets/js* directory, but when I try I get `$(...).DataTable is not a function`.

In my *app.js* I do import all the modules I need :

```
import 'select2';
import 'parsleyjs';
import 'datatables';
```

Here is my *webpack.config.js* :

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    // .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 years after this question, i had the same behaviour. After an entire night searching the Internet, i figured this out.

I'm using :

- **Symfony 6.3.4**
- **Webpack Encore 4.4.0**
- **JS Routing**

I installed all datatables libraries via :

```
npm install datatables.net-dt
npm install datatables.net-autofill-dt
npm install datatables.net-buttons-dt
npm install datatables.net-colreorder-dt
npm install datatables.net-fixedcolumns-dt
npm install datatables.net-fixedheader-dt
npm install datatables.net-keytable-dt
npm install datatables.net-rowgroup-dt
npm install datatables.net-rowreorder-dt
npm install datatables.net-responsive-dt
npm install datatables.net-scroller-dt
npm install datatables.net-searchbuilder-dt
npm install datatables.net-searchpanes-dt
npm install datatables.net-select-dt
npm install datatables.net-staterestore-dt
```

---

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this (i intentionnaly removed all the commented lines for clarity). You'll notice that i use a separate js file named **customjs_datatables.js**

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const FosRouting = require('fos-router/webpack/FosRouting');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('customjs_datatables', './assets/customjs_datatables.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .addPlugin(new FosRouting())
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Controller looks like this :

```
#[Route('/products/all', name: 'app_product_all')]
public function all(Request $request): Response
{
    $products = array(
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => "Iphone 6"
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => "Iphone 7"
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => "Iphone 8"
        ],
    );

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        # ajax feed
        return new JsonResponse($products);
    }

    return $this->render('product/all.html.twig', [
        "products" => $products,
    ]);
}
```

In framework.yaml :

```
fos_js_routing:
    routes_to_expose:
        - app_product_all
```

The all.html.twig file (notice the **{{ parent() }}** function) :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-2">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="p-3 border bg-light">
                <h2>{{'label_all_group_options'|trans}}</h2>
                <p>{{'descr_all_group_options'|trans}}</p>
                <table id="datatable_products" class="display p-1 m-0"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('customjs_datatables') }}
{% endblock %}
```

app.js looks like this :

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

import './styles/app.css';
import './styles/global.scss';

import Routing from 'fos-router';

const $ = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');
require('jqtree');

...
    
});
```

And the customjs_datatables.js file :

```
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-dt';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt';
 
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.mjs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.mjs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.mjs';
 
// DataTables initialisation
$('#datatable_products').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: window.location.href,
        dataSrc:""
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'name' },
    ]       
});
```

My root twig file named base.html.twig looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Bonus tip : after getting some issues styling my datatable, i added this to the top of my app.css file :

```
@import '~datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css';
```